# JOIN in CakePHP - A better understanding

Tags: cakephp, join, pagination

I'd like to understand `joins` in CakePHP (v 2.4.5) a bit better by solving the following example:

`Post hasMany Comment`
`Post.id == Comment.post_id`
`Comment.published` can be `1` or `0`

- I need to find all Posts that have at least one published Comment
- I want to write the query from the `Post` model. In order not to break pagination and so I can add order/conditions based on `Post`
- I do not want to filter out results afterwards in PHP (in order not to break pagination)

You might suggest to approach this issue from the `Comment` model like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3890461/155638
But this is about understanding joins better, so I'd like to set a requirement to write the query from the `Post` model.

I have roughly the following idea, hoping that the RIGHT join would exclude all non conforming Posts:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'comments',
            'alias' => 'CommentsJoined',
            'type' => 'RIGHT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Post.id = CommentsJoined.post_id',
                'CommentsJoined.published = true'
            )
        )
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Comment' => array(
             'conditions' => array(
                 'Comment.published' => 1
             )
        )
    )
);
```

But it did not work for me yet.
Currently my query returns 19 times the same Post, instead of 19 unique Posts.

How to go from here? Is the approach the right one?

Kind regards!
Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was on the right track. The final step was to remove the duplicate Posts.
This is done by adding `'group' => 'Post.id'` as an attribute to the query.

Like this:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'comments',
            'alias' => 'CommentsJoined',
            'type' => 'RIGHT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Post.id = CommentsJoined.post_id',
                'CommentsJoined.published = true'
            )
        )
    ),
    'group' => 'Post.id',
    'contain' => array(
        'Comment' => array(
             'conditions' => array(
                 'Comment.published' => 1
             )
        )
    )
);
```